# how to make Alert Dialog with transparent background color orange.Please look at the image

Tags: android, background-image, android-alertdialog, transparent

[This image is of alert box covering full screen with transparent orange background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhHi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to create it yourself. alerts can't be style.

Just make a div that displays when it's needed to, and disapears when they click yes/no...

Comment: no man.I have done it.It can be done through alert box properties

Comment: final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
  int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
  int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);
  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
  dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

Comment: so that would be a UI dialog, not an alert. perhaps you would have found the solution you were after if you worded your question better.